# in android, how to specify inches in an animation resource

Tags: android, animation

I want to specify an animation resource to use with Activity.overridePendingTransition. However the only available dimensions for the animations are %ages, pixels, etc but not inches. I need to use inches in my animation. Is there a workaround to this

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need to use inches? It's a rather peculiar requirement for Android :-)

Comment: either inches or density independent pixels. something that will make the it a uniform fraction of the screen size independent of dpi, and make it the same pixel length for both landscape and portait orientations

Comment: Oh I see. I don't develop for Android, but is there a way to grab the DPI of the device and use that to create a normalized unit?

Comment: I dont know if we can do such calculations in the resource files. They have to be static in my experience

Answer (score 1):

There's two ways to do this. The easiest (presumably, without seeing your code) is to define the number of DPs that you want for the animation in a [dimension xml resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension). You can then get this value converted into "local" pixels by calling [`getResources().getDimensionPixelSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimensionPixelSize%28int%29). That will get you what you want. Alternatively you can use the formula to convert from DPs to PX manually:  `px = dp * (dpi / 160)`

Comment: The thing is that for overridePendingTransition, you can just specify a static animation resource. How would you person these calculations in that case